# Trying to return records from database using c#

Tags: c#, sql, database

This is my code which i'm trying to return records back into a listview by entering different ID's. But i only seem to get the first record back no matter which ID i enter. Any help would be appreciated.

```
private void FindRecord()
        {
            List<SprocParameter> paramsSQL = new List<SprocParameter>();
            paramsSQL.Add(new SprocParameter("ID", textBoxID.Text) );

            DataSet ds = StoredProcedureExecute("get_ID", paramsSQL );

            if (null != ds && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count    > 0)
          {  
               textBoxID.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
               textBoxName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
              textBoxAddress.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0] 
            ["Address"].ToString();
            textBoxPhone.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Phone"].ToString();
           }
           else
           {
              textBoxID.Text = "Unrecognised ID";
              textBoxName.Text = "Incorrect Name";
              textBoxAddress.Text = "Wrong Address";
              textBoxPhone.Text = "Invalid Number";
           }
       }
```

Comment: because you are taking the first record only by using `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID"]`

Comment: Quite impossible to tell what's going wrong if we don't know what `get_ID` is, what `StoredProcedureExecute` does or how (and why) `SprocParameter` wraps things. These are not framework classes. Drill down until you get to actual `SqlCommand` code (or `DataAdapter`, more likely).

Comment: Besides only using `Rows[0]`, you seem to be assigning the data to `TextBox`es - not a `ListView`. Did you by any chance share the wrong code fragment? And could you explain how you would want to enter "different ID's" if there is only one `textBoxID.Text`?

Answer (score 0):

You aim is not entirely clear here, as you appear to be asking how to handle multiple rows but assigning these values to a text box which would suggest you only actually want one at a time. May I suggest executing the command stored procedure is a more readable way:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("peopleData");
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{               
        SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("get_ID", conn);               
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textBoxID.Text);

        sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;

        da.Fill(ds);
 }
```

Then the data can be accessed with something like this for a single row outputting to a textbox:

```
 DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]; // This will access the first row
 textBoxName.Text = dr["Name"].ToString();
```

Or if you are expecting your stored procedure to return many rows, you can iterate through them by doing something like the below. Although, in this case I suspect you wouldn't want to assign each value directly to the textbox, so it may be more appropriate deploy a ListView as suggested in the comments.:

```
foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)  // Only if you're expecting many datatables.
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        textBoxName.Text = dr["Name"].ToString();
    }
}
```